# set vibration length of wp7 click event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to set a vibration based upon a click event. The code works, however I am trying to match the vibration length of my button click events to the same vibration length of the actual phone's hardware buttons. This is what I am using right now and it seems to match fairly well.

```
VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(40));
```

Is this the correct length? And if not, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post may be interesting to you :-

http://blog.xyzzer.me/2012/01/09/vibration-behaviors-for-windows-phone-part-1/

It seems that the author has settled for a duration of 20ms.

Comment: Thanks @Paul I've seen elsewhere that 20 ms is a common timespan, although testing this it is evident that 20 ms is noticably shorter than the default hardware button vibrations. As far as I can tell 40 ms seems to be the most accurate amount, but If this is not the case I will post back.

Comment: I wonder if it might vary by phone slightly? Might be worth trying a few.